# Acceder a proipiedad de formulario en proceso principal desde otro en subproceso

Tags: c#

queria consultar si alguien sabe como acceder a las propiedades de un formulario desde otro en un subproceso del primero. Lo que quiero hacer es modificar la propiedad de visible desde el formulario 2 en un subproceso al formulario 1 en el proceso principal antes de cerrar el segundo. Estuve tratando usando delegados pero no pude hacerlo. A continuacion dejo el codigo.
Declaro la firma del delegado en el espacio de nombres y luego lo llamo desde el formulario secundario para acceder a metodo en el principal que se encuentra oculto.
Esto no me funcionò.
Gracias

```
public delegate void delegadoPrueba();
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    
   private Thread _procesoSecundario = null;
    
public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void boton_Cancelar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        
    }

    private void CrearFormulario()
    {
        Form1 formulario = new Form1();
        System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(formulario);
    }

    private void boton_Aceptar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        _procesoSecundario = new Thread(new ThreadStart(CrearFormulario));
        _procesoSecundario.IsBackground = true;
        _procesoSecundario.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA;
        _procesoSecundario.Start();
        
    this.Visible = false;
    }      

    public static void Visualizacion()
    {
                   
    }       
}
```

---

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{       
    
    public Form1()
    {
    InitializeComponent(); 
    this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(this.Cierre);
    }     

      
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }


   

    private void Cierre(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs ex)
    {

        if (MessageBox.Show("Desea cerrar el formulario ?", "Notificacion de Cierre", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question,                      MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button2) == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            ex.Cancel = true;
        }
       
            delegadoPrueba nuevodelegado = new delegadoPrueba();
            nuevodelegado();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no es posible modificar propiedades de un control desde otro hilo. Lo que puedes hacer es que tu hilo secundario desencadene una accion en el hilo de la UI con `Control.Invoke` o `Control.BeginInvoke`.

La diferencia entre las dos es que al usar `Invoke` tu hilo secudario espera a que se haya ejecutado la acción en el hilo de la UI. Sinembargo al usar `BeginInvoke` mientras se está ejecutando la acción en el hilo de la UI tu hilo secudario puede estar haciendo otras cosas.

Aqui te dejo los enlaces a la documentación oficial y a algunos foros donde preguntan lo mismo: [Invoke](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) , [BeginInvoke](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.begininvoke?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) y [foro](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/d12917b9-e9a9-4561-abdb-07504b61e03f/comunicacin-de-controles-del-hilo-principal-con-un-hilo-secundario-provoca-excepciones-en-tiempo-de?forum=vcses)